# What's the point of the cataloginventory_stock_status_idx table?

Tags: magento

I have tried really hard to understand the cataloginventory_stock relations - I do know that both the stock_item as well as stock_status tables get updated when a stock item gets modified, but I wasn't able to figure out whether the stock_status_idx table is really required.

From what I can see, the stock_status_idx table contains the same information as the stock_status table. Is it a temporary table only? I did not see any problems with wrong stock status if I manually updated the stock_item and stock_status tables, but did not update the stock_status_idx table.

The thing is.. I thought it's somehow used for caching/the indexer. However, even if I didn't modify the stock_status_idx table, the stock status displayed just fine in the backend and in the frontend.

So, what's the point of the stock_status_idx table?

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 12):

I was wondering the same question and decided to dig as I could not find an answer anywhere.
It seems like the _tmp and _idx are used as temp holders for your indexed data.

For example, you can look at the `reindexAll()` method in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Indexer/Product.php` and you will understand that it is using _idx tables to temporarily store it's data when generating the indexes:

```
$this->useIdxTable(true);
...
$idxTable = $this->getIdxTable();
....
$query = $select->insertFromSelect($idxTable, ...
```

At the end of the same method you will notice a nice `$this->syncData()` method call. You probably guessed it! The function lives in  `app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php` and is doing just that, syncs the _idx with main:

```
$this->_getWriteAdapter()->delete($this->getMainTable());
$this->insertFromTable($this->getIdxTable(), $this->getMainTable(), false);
$this->commit();
```

Best of luck!

Comment: This answer should get accepted. Thanks! Same answer in other words: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/35518/6291

Answer (score 2):

idx table is used only when Magento need select many products based on their stock item, so the index on these tables are faster than use the main inventory tables.

I recommend you to write your data onto this table too. Or better, use Magento API or Magento App over PHP to write into Magento Database, is much more safe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

That's not the technical answer I would have expected unfortunately. Do you know which function actually regenerates the idx table? No matter what I found, reindexProducts($ids), reindexAll - none reindexed the idx table. ONLY when I saved the product in the backend. But I wasn't able to find what initiates this. Even when I reindex the stock entity in Magento at Index Management, it doesn't refresh. Thanks!

Comment: The exact usage of this table is in `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Mysql4_Indexer_Stock_Default::_prepareIndexTable()` and configurable/grouped product in their respective classes too. Search for `getIdxTable()`. There is a call to `insertFromSelect` that effectively inserts into `cataloginventory_stock_status_idx`.

Comment: _idx tables are temporary index tables in Magento. ie. they are populated during a reindex process and are then emptied out when the reindex process is completed.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this for the same reason (to update stock quantities directly in Mysql) and will use the built in  indexer feature of Magento with the "cataloginventory_stock" . I like this feature since it only takes a few seconds to run on my server.

you can reach the magento indexer and get some nice information

/[your store home]/shell  then run: /usr/bin/php -f indexer.php info

here is the crontab line for running just the catalog inventory re-index:
30 3 * * * /usr/bin/php -f /home/client/www/shell/indexer.php -- --reindex cataloginventory_stock