# What is the purpose of cataloginventory_stock_status_idx & cataloginventory_stock_status_tmp in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

What are the purpose of **_idx** & **_tmp** tables in Magento databases. How data in these tables get updated ?

I have seen that during cataloginventory_stock indexing Magento first deletes the data from table cataloginventory_stock_status & then finally inserts data inside data in this table by running the query

```
"INSERT INTO cataloginventory_stock_status SELECT * FROM cataloginventory_stock_status_idx";
```

But I want to understand the purpose of _idx & _tmp table, when & why Magento updates data in _idx & _tmp table. As far as I know these are not master product inventory tables.

Comment: Since Magento is highly normalized, it have tables to save less normalized data in *_idx tables. *_idx is updated when you run indexing process from Magento Admin or via shell indexer.php script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the point of the cataloginventory\_stock\_status\_idx table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063434/whats-the-point-of-the-cataloginventory-stock-status-idx-table)

Answer (score 3):

I was wondering the same question and decided to dig as I could not find an answer anywhere.
It seems like the _tmp and _idx are used as temp holders for your indexed data.

For example, you can look at the `reindexAll()` method in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Indexer/Product.php` and you will understand that it is using _idx tables to temporarily store it's data when generating the indexes:

```
$this->useIdxTable(true);
...
$idxTable = $this->getIdxTable();
....
$query = $select->insertFromSelect($idxTable, ...
```

At the end of the same method you will notice a nice `$this->syncData()` method call. You probably guessed it! The function lives in  `app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php` and is doing just that, syncs the _idx with main:

```
$this->_getWriteAdapter()->delete($this->getMainTable());
$this->insertFromTable($this->getIdxTable(), $this->getMainTable(), false);
$this->commit();
```

Best of luck!